# Making a HTTP API request to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to make a HTTP get request to

https://elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?ApplicationName=MyApplicationName&Operation=DescribeEnvironments

and getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/docs/2010-12-01/>
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
        <Message>No account found for the given parameters</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>ca83cbc7-f22a-11e3-8380-3bbf7df037f3</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I've tried setting my key and secret as username and password for basic HTTP auth, but clearly this doesn't work.

So how do I add my key and secret to my remote request?

Answer (score 1):

For most AWS usage scenarios it is highly recommended to use one of the many [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to ease working with the APIs via higher level abstractions - these SDKs also take care of the required and slightly complex request signing, an explanation for the usually several options how to provide your AWS credentials can be found in the resp. SDK documentation:

> The AWS SDKs provide functions that wrap an API and take care of many of the connection details, such as calculating signatures, handling request retries, and error handling. The SDKs also contain sample code, tutorials, and other resources to help you get started writing applications that call AWS. Calling the wrapper functions in an SDK can greatly simplify the process of writing an AWS application.

If you *really* have a need to use the AWS APIs via REST directly, [Signing AWS API Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) will guide you through the required steps, see e.g. section *Components of an AWS Signature 4 Request* within [Signature Version 4 Signing Process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) for the one that applies to [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

- Please note that several services augment that documentation with a tailored one, see e.g. [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) for the Amazon S3 variation.